# Recursively building a string

Tags: c, string, recursion

so I'm trying to build a string recursively but I can't get it to work. This is how a part of my code looks like :

```
void afiseaza(TRNod *nod,char *x,int niv,int w)
{

    if(nod==NULL)
        return;
    int i;

    *(x+niv)=w;
    *(x+niv+1)='\0';
    // x[niv]=w,x[niv+1]='\0'

    if(nod->sf==1)
        printf("%s\n %d \n",x,niv);
    niv++;

    for(i=0;i<36;i++)
    {
        afiseaza(nod->fiu[i],&x,niv,i+87);
    }

}
```

basically TRNod is a node of a tree, and if the node is allocated it corresponds to a letter in the alphabet.

Comment: And you are putting `afiseaza` inside of a loop

Comment: You have to increment `niv` twice.

Answer (score 0):

The function takes a `char *` (pointer-to-char) as the second argument...

```
void afiseaza(TRNod *nod,char *x,int niv,int w)
```

... but you're giving it a `char **` (pointer-to-pointer-to-char):

```
afiseaza(nod->fiu[i],&x,niv,i+87);
```

Really, a compiler should warn about this, and the programmer should heed to the warnings.